# What is difference between a monogenic system and a dynamical system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, definition, complex-systems

What is difference between a [monogenic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system) and a [dynamical system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system)?
I am confused in  reading about the Hamiltonian principle because some book write system as monogenic and other dynamical.

Although they give the description of monogenic, I want to know is there a specific difference or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system
is wiki not enough? It looks like a dynamical system where you can write the generalized forces using a generalized potential in a form that resembles that of the lagrangian equation. This way, you should be able to define a "generalized Lagrangian" and treat the EOM as generalized Lagrange equations

Answer (score 0):

A dynamical system is an evolving "system" in its broadest meaning. While a monogenic system is a specific class of systems in classical mechanics.

From the OP's wikilinks (my emphasis):

> a **dynamical system** is a system in which a function describes the time dependence of a point in an ambient space. Examples include the mathematical models that describe [...] pendulum [...] water [...] particles in the air [...] number of fish

> In classical mechanics, a physical system is termed a **monogenic system** if [...] all forces, with the exception of the constraint forces, are derivable from the generalized scalar potential, and this generalized scalar potential is a function of generalized coordinates, generalized velocities, or time

Dynamical systems theory is a area of mathematics which concerns itself with the qualitative behavior of any evolving mathematical system; it can be informally called *nonlinear dynamics* when done by physicists: who often won't bother to restrict their areas of research to the traditional branches of physics, and certainly not to mechanical systems only.